# Partial Map with a dictionary in Pandas (python), Return attributes error

Tags: python, pandas

The following is a sub-set of a dictionary:

```
equiv= {'Urin problem': 'C0/ Urine', 'disorientation': 'C0233407 / Disorientation', 'fatigue': 'C0015672 / Fatigue', 'headache': 'C334 / headache'}
```

I am going to map the following data to this dictionary:

```
drug_id       WD
lexapro.1   minor urin problem
lexapro.1   Fatigue
lexapro.1   disorientation
lexapro.1   tiredness
lexapro.14  dizziness
lexapro.14  headaches
```

The output should be like this:

```
drug_id        WD                           Map              Exact_Match

lexapro.1   minor urin problem      C0/ Urine       
lexapro.1   Fatigue                'C0015672 / Fatigue                 1
lexapro.1   disorientation          C0233407 / Disorientation          1
lexapro.1   tiredness           
lexapro.14  dizziness           
lexapro.14  headaches                C334 / headache
```

As you see if it can find the exact map, the column of Exact_Match will be filled with 1, like Fatigue and disorientation. And if the item is partial map, the Map column will have the corresponding value, but The exact match column does not get any value. This is my code:

```
df['Map'] = df["WD"].str.extract('('+'|'.join(list(equiv))+')').map(equiv).fillna(1),
```

but it has the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`. But when I use this code: `df['Map'] = df["WD"].map(equiv).fillna(1)`, there is no error. However it does not help with partial match. `I also do not know how to fill in the Exact_Match column with 1 when there is exact match.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using the following vectorized approach:

```
mp = pd.DataFrame({'WD':[x.lower() for x in equiv.keys()],
                   'Map':[x for x in equiv.values()]})
df['Map'] = \
    df.WD.str.lower().replace(
        (r'.*\b' + mp.WD + r'[\b\n\r]*.*').tolist(),
        mp.Map.tolist(),
        regex=True
    )
df['Exact_Match'] = df.WD.str.lower().isin(mp.WD.str.lower()).astype(np.uint8)
df.loc[df.WD.eq(df.Map), 'Map'] = ''
```

Demo:

```
In [47]: mp = pd.DataFrame({'WD':[x.lower() for x in equiv.keys()],
    ...:                    'Map':[x for x in equiv.values()]})
    ...:

In [48]: mp
Out[48]:
                         Map              WD
0            C334 / headache        headache
1                  C0/ Urine    urin problem
2         C0015672 / Fatigue         fatigue
3  C0233407 / Disorientation  disorientation

In [49]: df['Map'] = \
    ...:     df.WD.str.lower().replace(
    ...:         (r'.*\b' + mp.WD + r'[\b\n\r]*.*').tolist(),
    ...:         mp.Map.tolist(),
    ...:         regex=True
    ...:     )
    ...:

In [50]: df['Exact_Match'] = df.WD.str.lower().isin(mp.WD.str.lower()).astype(np.uint8)

In [51]: df.loc[df.WD.eq(df.Map), 'Map'] = ''

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
      drug_id                  WD                        Map  Exact_Match
0   lexapro.1  minor urin problem                  C0/ Urine            0
1   lexapro.1             Fatigue         C0015672 / Fatigue            1
2   lexapro.1      disorientation  C0233407 / Disorientation            1
3   lexapro.1           tiredness                                       0
4  lexapro.14           dizziness                                       0
5  lexapro.14           headaches            C334 / headache            0
```

Comment: your solution is great. Is there anyway to remove the values, such as tiredness and dizziness from Map column? There is no value for them in the dictionary.

Comment: for this part of code:  "mp = pd.DataFrame({'WD':[x.lower() for x in equiv.keys()]",  there is this error "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'". Do you know the reason?

Comment: sorry, my fault. The dictionary file was open.

Answer (score 2):

I would likely do this in a few different steps as I think there is actually a fair amount going on here. For matching strings you might want to try something like python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

The first line is setting the value equal to 1 if the exact string is in the dictionary keys otherwise returns null. The second line uses difflib to get the closest match of a string to the keys. You can check the docs on information for setting the threshold of similarity to return. The third line then uses the list of similar keys previously generated to return the values from the dictionary. There may be a simpler way to achieve this but this is how I would approach the problem

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
import numpy as np

#Set the exact match column if the cell value is in the dictionary keys
df['Exact_Match'] = df['WD'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in equiv.keys() else np.nan)

#Get the keys that for the dictionary based on close matches
df_keys = df.WD.apply(lambda x: ''.join(get_close_matches(x, equiv.keys(), n=1, cutoff=0.8)))

#return the values of those keys and create a new column for the values
df['MAP'] = [equiv[e] if e else '' for e in df_keys]


    drug_id     WD                  Exact_Match    MAP
0   lexapro.1   minor urin problem  NaN            C0/ Urine
1   lexapro.1   Fatigue             NaN            C0015672 / Fatigue
2   lexapro.1   disorientation      1.0            C0233407 / Disorientation
3   lexapro.1   tiredness           NaN 
4   lexapro.14  dizziness           NaN 
5   lexapro.14  headaches           NaN            C334 / headache
```

​

Comment: Thank you. I tested your code on the entire data, and there is the following error: "df4['MAP'] = [equiv[e] if e else '' for e in df_keys]
KeyError: 'dizzinessdrowsiness'" I check the two keys: dizziness" and "drowsiness", there were not problem with these keys and their values. Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: Oh yes, the get `get_close_matches` function was returning *all* keys that were similar and the the `.join` method was joining them. I added a `n=1` to the function so that it should only return the closest match. That should fix the issue

Comment: this solution has a problem. If the data frame has "neck pain", it maps it to " eye pain" to dictionary. Do you know the reason ?

Comment: This happens because difflib is looking for strings that are similar to each other; "neck pain" and "eye pain" are quite similar to each other so it sees them as a match. Increasing the threshold `get_close_matches('neck pain', ['eye pain'], cutoff=0.8)` for instance will not return eye pain, though changing the cutoff to 0.6 will. This is a feature of difflib that I really like for string matching - the ability to quickly make adjustments to matching, though it may not be the best solution for your use case.

Comment: It is a great solution. So you mean, we need to define a cutoff  point for each similar item separately, or there is a general way to define cutoff for get_close_matches ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134808/discussion-between-johnchase-and-mary).

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat similar to MaxU's approach (based on `replace()`) and about the same speed for this tiny example and slower than johnchase's.

But you may want to test on a larger and more realistic dataframe.  I just expanded it to 1500 rows and this was the fastest way (followed by MaxU's and then johnchase's) but that might not necessarily hold on your actual data.

```
equiv2 = dict( ( k.lower(), v ) for k,v in equiv.items() )
df['Map'] = df.WD.str.lower().replace( equiv2, regex=True )
df.loc[ df.Map == df.WD, 'Map' ] = ''
df['Exact'] = df.WD.isin(equiv).astype(int)

df
Out[166]: 
      drug_id                  WD                        Map  Exact
0   lexapro.1  minor urin problem            minor C0/ Urine      0
1   lexapro.1             Fatigue         C0015672 / Fatigue      0
2   lexapro.1      disorientation  C0233407 / Disorientation      1
3   lexapro.1           tiredness                                 0
4  lexapro.14           dizziness                                 0
5  lexapro.14           headaches           C334 / headaches      0
```

The third line (`df.loc`) feels kind of redundant or hacky but I couldn't figure out a way to make `replace` return NaN or such for non-matches so I just converted "Map" to a `''` if "WD" == "Map".  Shouldn't slow things down all that much but seems like there would be a better way...

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to replace 1 in Map column with empty string. I do not have a large data set.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this solution is , When there is WD in data frame such as " anxiety very severe", it can find the corresponding  item in dictionary but the value in Map column include the dictionary value plus the rest of the term in WD column. For example it returns, "C140\anxious very severe".

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't think about that (but now I notice the "minor" in my Map column that should't be there.  probably fixable although I don't have an easy answer.  it looks like the other answers may do a better job, so I'll just leave this alone for now and fix later if I think of something.